# Reading float values using scipy.io.loadmat() - is bit accurate?

Tags: matlab, scipy

I would like to transfer single-precision float values from Matlab/Simulink into my Python script. Data in Matlab/Simulink are saved into V7 MAT file (so that I can use scipy.io.loadmat()). Those float values are found in a Python dictionary after loadmat().
My question is whether or not the float value I get in Python is identical to the one originally in Matlab/Simulink down to the last bit.

For example, a float value, 0.32 is ‘00111110101000111101011100001010’.
When this "0.32" is read into Python, can I reproduce exact bit representation, nothing more, nothing less?

Answer (score 2):

Both MATLAB and Python use the IEEE 754 single precision format to represent 32-bit floating point numbers - you can guarantee that both will represent the same float value using the exact same representation.

Answer (score 0):

I have generated binary string from a float value from MATLAB/Simulink environment and from Python environment (after scipy.io.loadmat()). They are identical to the last bit. Therefore, you can use scipy.io.loadmat() to transfer data to Python environment bit accurately.